# is it right to say ' provide huge job opportunities to society'

Tags: grammar

I'm writing an essay, when I meet the grammar issue.
the 'to society' is right? or should use 'to the society'?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You use "to society."

You might use "to the society" when talking about a specific smaller organization such as the American Society for the Prevention of Cruelty to Animals.